# autoProcessQueue=false not working in dropzone.js

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, dropzone.js

i am trying to use dropzone.js in my web application. I am succesfull in uploading single/multi files with dropzone.

But I am trying to send formData with the files. So I have set the autoprocess queue to false.

With these settings files are not waiting for my response, they just start uploading automatically.

See my settings here..

```
  var DrZone = new Dropzone("#uploadmore", { url: "GalleryHandler.ashx" });
        Dropzone.options.DrZone = {
            previewsContainer: ".dropzone-previews",
            uploadMultiple: true,
            parallelUploads: 100,
            maxFiles: 100,
            autoProcessQueue: false,
            init: function () {
                this.on("sending", function (file, xhr, formData) {   formData.append("AlbumId", 2); });
            }

        };
```

Anything wrong in my settings?
And when I see in my Handler for the posted Data it is always null!!

```
   var obj = context.Request["AlbumId"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to handle the options array as parameter to dropzone.js like in [my example](http://jsfiddle.net/9Lhrkmr4/).

```
var DrZone = new Dropzone(document.getElementById("dropzone"), {
  url: "GalleryHandler.ashx",
  previewsContainer: ".dropzone-previews",
  uploadMultiple: true,
  parallelUploads: 100,
  maxFiles: 100,
  autoProcessQueue: false  
});
```

When you want to define callback functions, try it like this:

```
DrZone.on("totaluploadprogress", function (progress) {
  // your code
});
```

For more infos checkout the [bootstrap example page](http://www.dropzonejs.com/bootstrap.html)

Answer (score 0):

it is not working, once you have autoProcessQueue: false  no action is called